# Python is taking up all of my CPU!

Tags: python

I noticed that my computer was running slowly, and that the CPU was at 80-99% all the time, so I opened my Task Manager, and I see that Python is taking up almost all of it. How do I fix this?

Comment: please edit your question to include the output of the following command: ps -ef | grep python

Comment: Python is a programming language, lot's of apps use it. One of them is misbehaving, use the command above to find which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful

do a

```
ps -ef | grep python
```

in a terminal, find the processes that you think shouldn't be running, and kill them with

```
kill PID
```

PID for the process is given in the first column of the `ps` output.